# What are some good Paid Document Preview products?

Tags: list, document-library, search-results

We have a need to implement document preview for "LIST" and "Search Results" for bunch of common file types (all office, msg, dwg, pdf, images, etc.). What are some good products out there for this? Keeping budget to reasonable.

I found some but most of the looks like they are doing business out of garage. Because they never pick up phone (some dont even have a phone number). I left them messages and but never heard from them.

I left numerous email for the one dont have phone numbers. It's the same story.

Comment: What version of SharePoint are you using?

Answer (score 1):

there are many as you said but here are couple reputable and according to your requirement.

[HarePoint Thumbnails for SharePoint ​​​​​​](http://www.harepoint.com/Products/HarePointThumbnails/Default.aspx)
HarePoint, The product allows you to browse content before downloading – a major time-saver that increases SharePoint end-users productivity. Key Fratures:
Instant document preview directly in SharePoint libraries,  Preview everywhere, Adjustable preview settings
And supported files are:

Microsoft Office applications (Word (.doc; .docx), Excel (.xls; .xlsx.));
PDF;
Images (.bmp, .gif, .jpeg, .png, .tif and many others);
Web pages (html, htm, mht);
E-mail messages (eml, msg).
Plain text (.txt)

[Vizit Essential](http://www.vizit.com/vizit-essential/)
Discover and share SharePoint content
Vizit Essential™ builds on Vizit’s legacy as the fastest and most efficient file preview and viewing solution available for Microsoft SharePoint. Vizit Essential offers cutting edge search, collaboration, workflow and third party integrations. Vizit Essential greatly improves SharePoint 2013 usability by extending the platform’s preview and viewing capabilities with important formats including PDF, Email (.msg, .eml, .emlx), TIF, DWG and hundreds of other file types.

Answer (score 0):

I think BA Insight, http://www.bainsight.com/Pages/home.aspx, is the leader in search enhancements to Sharepoint. I recall they have preview capabilities as well as a slew of other things.

Comment: it's 500K for their product. WAY too much.